# How to solve npm errors like below in react

Tags: npm-start

I'm new at react.js. Currently i'm trying to explore about react.js but after install creact-react-app using npm or yarn .Then wrote npm start but Still facing Invalid options object and npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE too .

```
$ npm start

> random-users@0.1.0 start C:\Users\0x702!\Desktop\Today\New folder\random-users
> react-scripts start

Invalid options object. React Refresh Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options.overlay.module: The provided value "C:\\Users\\0x702!\\Desktop\\Today\\New folder\\random-users\\node_modules\\react-dev-utils\\refreshOverlayInterop.js" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! random-users@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the random-users@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\0x702!\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-14T15_40_45_603Z-debug.log
```

**When i wrote yarn start the program shows me an error like below:**

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts start
Invalid options object. React Refresh Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match
 the API schema.
 - options.overlay.module: The provided value "C:\\Users\\0x702!\\Desktop\\Today\\New folder\\random-users\\n
ode_modules\\react-dev-utils\\refreshOverlayInterop.js" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed be
cause it's reserved for loader syntax.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "random-users",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Please guy's help me. I'm tried to solve this problem . **

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **its time to learn how to read errors ;)**

Path contains **exclamation mark**, which is for loader syntax and **cannot be used in that way.**

Just rename `C:\Users\0x702!` folder to `0x702`  or create another user to solve your problem :)